# Windows cant find path : Permissions lost to access a folder's files

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, file-management, file-permissions

I have a huge folder named Softwares_New which has all my softwares dump, it is 177 GB in size. As I observed, all the files and folders lacked permission to access them. I went into folder properties, unchecked the hidden attribute, applied to all the files. Now I get an error stating 

**"Error: Cannot apply attributes, access is denied."** It was pretty weird, All the folders were accessible but files like EXEs and ZIPs failed to open. What i tried doing was to go to file's properties, under security tab, clicked on advanced, added a new principal, allowed complete access and then i could access them. Is there any way in which I can apply the same security permissions to all my 94 items? Here is an image of folder properties' security tab : [image] As you can see, we get an error after opening ZIP or RAR files and we dont have permissions to access EXEs.

Please suggest a method to do it all at once, it becomes really tough to chane security permissions foe each file/folder.
This is a windows 10 machine which got updated yesterday.
Please help me, this folder is very important to me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to take ownership of the folder and the files contained within it in order to fix any permission problems it might have.

Comment: @Ramhound should i do that for each of my file? It is a tough task to do that right? Can i do that at once?

Comment: If you can't duplicate the problem in a couple dozen lines of code, you likely have not, identified the simplest code possible to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From an elevated cmd prompt run the following three commands (Change your Username on the 3rd command). This will take ownership of all the files, reset the permissions and grant you full access.

```
takeown /R /F D:\Softwares_New
icacls D:\Softwares_New /reset /T /C
icacls D:\Softwares_New /grant "JSrinivas V:(OI)(CI)F"
```